# How to get a user input and find its corresponding key from an array and display it n PHP

Tags: php

I have a file that I am reading the data from, the file has postcode and its corresponding state in this format :

```
3001,MELBOURNE
```

I will be accepting the state name as input from the user and then check its corresponding postcode from the array key and display the result. I am able to read the full file and display the result in a table but don't know how to go beyond.

This is what I was able to do :

```
if (isset($_GET['suburb'])) {
    $suburb = strtoupper($_GET['suburb']);
    echo $suburb;
    $file = "postcode.txt";
    if(!file_exists($file)) {
        echo "No record found!";
    }
    else {
        $records = file($file);
        echo "<table border='1'><th>Postcode</th><th>State</th>";
        for($i=0;$i<count($records);$i++) {
            $arr = explode(",",$records[$i]);
            echo "<tr><td>".$arr[0]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$arr[1]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Comment: a database would be better for this, or at least a better data format, eg json. Do you have to user this text file in this format?

Answer (score 0):

you could just iterate the file lines until you find a match:

```
foreach(file($file) as $line){
    list($postcode, $state) = explode(',', $line);
    if($state == $suburb){
        echo $postcode;
        break;
    }
}
```

But a database would be a better option if you are performing a lot of searches or the file grows large